# Given that the quadratic equation $x^2-px+q=0$ has two roots $r$ and $s,$ Find the quadratic equation that takes $r^3$ and $s^3$ as its roots.

Tags: quadratics

Here's what I've tried:

Using Vieta's formulas: 
$\;rs = q\;$ and $\,r+s = p$.

Then I cubed $rs$ which is $q^3$ and $(r+s)^3 + rs$ which is $p^3 + pq.$ Thinking that $x^2 - (p^3+pq)x + q^3$ is the answer. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Why did you take $(r+s)^3+rs$?  Note that if your new quadratic equation is $x^2-ax+b$, then (using the Vieta formulas again) $b=r^3s^3$ (which you correlated well) but $a=r^3+s^3$, which doesn't correspond to anything that you suggested.

Comment: `and (r+s)^3+rs` You may want to elaborate this step some more (and realize why it's wrong). Rather, think at using $\,(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)\,$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation in question would look like
$$(x-r^3)(x-s^3)=x^2-(r^3+s^3)x+r^3s^3=0$$
As you've already identified, the last term is $(rs)^3=q^3$.

The coefficient of $-x$ is
$$\begin{split}
r^3+s^3 &= (r+s)(r^2-rs+s^2) \\
&= p(r^2+2rs+s^2-3rs) \\
&= p\bigg((r+s)^2-3rs\bigg) \\
&= p(p^2-3q)
\end{split}$$
Therefore, the equation is
$$x^2 -p(p^2-3q)x +q^3=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the following identities

$$r^3+s^3=(r+s)^3-3rs(r+s)$$

$$r^3s^3=(rs)^3$$

You know that  $r+s=p$ and $rs=q$ by Vieta's formulas. Hence, the desired polynomial is given by

$$p(x)=x^2-(p^3-3qp)x+q^3$$